# mplfinance: plot a line without using an "ohlc" DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, mplfinance

I would like to plot a line without using a *"default ohlc data"*.
In this case, I'm using the data in the [Github](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/tree/master/examples/data).

How can I do this?

```
import pandas as pd
import mplfinance as mpf
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import numpy as np


path_ = 'C:\Mypath'

intraday = pd.read_csv(path_+'SP500_NOV2019_IDay.csv',index_col=0,parse_dates=True)
intraday.index.name = 'Date'


# mpf.plot(intraday,type='line')    #ohlc DataFrame.. ok


int_Low = intraday.loc[:,'Low']     #non ohlc DataFrame
mpf.plot(data=int_Low,type='line')  #doesn't work
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that mplfinance is designed around a base OHLC chart. One way to make a Low line is to add it to the chart:

```
lowline = mpf.make_addplot(intraday['Low'], type='line')
mpf.plot(intraday, addplot=lowline)
```

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, as mplfinance is now, when plotting `type='line'` then `mpf.plot(data,type='line')` will, by default, use the 'Close' column.

One possible work-around would be to put your 'Low' data into the 'Close' column.

```py
df = pd.read_csv('examples/data/SP500_NOV2019_IDay.csv',index_col=0,parse_dates=True)
df['RealClose'] = df['Close'].values  # save close values in case want them later
df['Close'] = df['Low'].values        # set 'Close' column to low values
mpf.plot(df,type='line')              # plot 'Low' as a line
```

---

Another solution might be to enhance mplfinance to accept a kwarg called `use_column`.  Then, for example, one could simply write:

```py
df = pd.read_csv('examples/data/SP500_NOV2019_IDay.csv',index_col=0,parse_dates=True)
mpf.plot(df,type='line',use_column='Low')
```

This enhancement is relatively easy to implement (just a few lines of code).  Please let me know, in a comment below, if you are interested in contributing to mplfinance.  Full disclosure: I am the maintainer of mplfinance.

Comment: Ok I would like to contribute, absolutely. I appreciate your job!